# ActionMap / InputMap to make JTextArea display "this text" when F2 is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, key-bindings, key-events

I've been trying to make a JTextArea display a certain String when F2 is pressed in a certain TextField, with no success as yet. Any help much appreciated.

My code may reveal how little programming experience I have:

```
final String ACTION_KEY = "this text";

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                JTextField source = (JTextField) actionEvent.getSource();

                System.out.println("Activated: " + source.getText());

                textAreaInstructions.setText("this text");

              }
            };


            KeyStroke F2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2");
            InputMap inputMap = timeStep.getInputMap();
            inputMap.put(F2, ACTION_KEY);
            ActionMap actionMap = timeStep.getActionMap();          
            actionMap.put(ACTION_KEY, actionListener);
```

EDIT: I'm now trying this code instead:

```
InputMap inputMap = timeStep.getInputMap();
        Object actionSubmit = inputMap.get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"));
        Object actionSubmitSp = inputMap.get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"));
        System.out.println("actionSubmit for space = " + actionSubmitSp);
        ActionMap actionMap = timeStep.getActionMap();
        Action action = actionMap.get(actionSubmit);
        System.out.println("actionSubmit = " + actionSubmit);
        timeStep.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),
                actionSubmit);
```

EDIT:

This prints

```
actionSubmit for space = null
actionSubmit = notify-field-accept
```

Is this any use?

Comment: Are you need to refresh text in JTextArea always? or you need to refresh it only by pressing key?

Comment: only by pressing F2 (well, it's tab I want actually, but I know there can be other issues relating to tab, so I thought I'd try with F2 first)

Comment: I don't get what is your problem? Are you having problem using `KeyBindings` ? Try to read this [How to use KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: My problem was nothing to do with the code posted. It was that I'd saved a backup of the file in the same package as the original and forgot to change the code, so the backup was being implemented rather than the updated original. That cost me a lot of time. lol. That said, I haven't yet made sure I do understand how to make this work: I'd been on the pc for a long time when i posted this and I've only just come back online. +1 for your help.

Comment: Problem solved: see answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was nothing to do with the code posted. It was that I'd saved a backup of the file in the same package as the original and forgot to change the code, so the backup was being implemented rather than the updated original. That cost me a lot of time. lol.

EDIT: so anyway, now that I know which file I'm running, I found that the following code (which I got here: http://blog.marcnuri.com/blog/.../2007/06/06/Detecting-Tab-Key-Pressed-Event-in-JTextField-s-Event-VK-TAB-KeyPressed) does what I wanted (for tab instead of F2, but would obviously work for F2 too, in which case the first line wouldn't be needed):

```
timeStep.setFocusTraversalKeys(
                KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, Collections.EMPTY_SET);

        timeStep.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB){
                    instruction = "tab pressed";
                    textAreaInstructions.setText(instruction);
                    lblTabEvent.setText(instruction);
                    // If you want to change the focus to the next component 
                    timerInterval.grabFocus();
            }
                else {

                    textAreaInstructions.setText("got here, "+ e.getKeyCode());
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: This bit of it is. Whether I'll get further problems because tab is a treated a bit differently or for some other reason, I don't know yet.

Comment: try to use `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled()` for hook VK_TAB on your field

Comment: +1 for help Thanks: I've seen posts relating to tab. i'm just trying with F2 or space first. I'm using some different code now (see EDIT). Actually, I'm not sure the above prob is solved yet, with the original or EDIT code. It's printing  actionSubmit for space = null

Comment: Next code prints **actionSubmit for space = SPACE1** for me. `KeyStroke F2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE");
        InputMap inputMap = area.getInputMap();
        inputMap.put(F2, "SPACE1");
        Object actionSubmit = inputMap.get(F2);
        System.out.println("actionSubmit for space = " + actionSubmit);`

Comment: Why doesn't it print the same for me, I wonder? My comment doesn't show all of what it prints: I'll put it in another edit to the question. +1 for your help.